# Send TCP packet in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, websocket

I tried to send a TCP packed data to a some ip with php , i used the code below to send it :

```
$socket=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    //$bind=socket_bind($socket,'tcp://94.232.171.102');

socket_connect($socket, 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 9001);
$buff='P\00\00\00\e5G\1f\b9\c6\acB\84\15\e7\b3*\17\ab\00G2\n\9c\ba{\a9}\dab"\c31\ed\f7\94\fc\aeX\ab\13\r/\02\ce\83f\bc?\96q\10M\b0\f4\a0\b1\95X\d0\85\10\df$|\de$\b4\f6m\a9\ff%Z\b4\d8\aa\da\bb';
$length = strlen($buff);
$sent = socket_write($socket, $buff, $length);
```

But, however, it doesnt work and doesnt sent , when i use some windows application like [Packet Sender](http://packetsender.com/) for that setting it's send packet correctly , why i cant send it from php on localhost

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what the problem is? What's the value of `$sent`? What did you expect? What gets sent, if anything?

Comment: sent answer is  number 198 and when it's work correctly it must do a job on a web application , but it's not work with php code , but work correcctly by packet sender application with same setting

Comment: So what is the actual problem? So, `$sent` is supposed to be 198, and it actually is?

Comment: the problem is this code dont do any action on real world ( my web application that listen to this port and recive data ) but if i use this setting with packet sender it's work well ...

Comment: We must be talking past each other. I still have no idea what value `$sent` has when you run this code, though I've asked you twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With at least some error handling you have a better chance of finding the error.

```
ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL); // <- for debugging purposes only

$socket=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ( !$socket ) {
    $errno = socket_last_error();
    $error = sprintf('%s (%d)', socket_strerror($errno), $errno);
    trigger_error($error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

if ( !socket_connect($socket, 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 9001) ) {
    $errno = socket_last_error($socket);
    $error = sprintf('%s (%d)', socket_strerror($errno), $errno);
    trigger_error($error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$buff='P\00\00\00\e5G\1f\b9\c6\acB\84\15\e7\b3*\17\ab\00G2\n\9c\ba{\a9}\dab"\c31\ed\f7\94\fc\aeX\ab\13\r/\02\ce\83f\bc?\96q\10M\b0\f4\a0\b1\95X\d0\85\10\df$|\de$\b4\f6m\a9\ff%Z\b4\d8\aa\da\bb';
$length = strlen($buff);
$sent = socket_write($socket, $buff, $length);
if ( FALSE===$sent ) {
    $errno = socket_last_error($socket);
    $error = sprintf('%s (%d)', socket_strerror($errno), $errno);
    trigger_error($error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
else if ( $length!==$sent ) {
    $msg = sprintf('only %d of %d bytes sent', $length, $sent);
    trigger_error($msg, E_USER_NOTICE);
}
```